# Finding Proper Nouns using NLTK WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Is there any way to find proper nouns using NLTK WordNet?Ie., Can i tag Possessive nouns using nltk Wordnet ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I don't think you need WordNet to find proper nouns, I suggest using the Part-Of-Speech tagger `pos_tag`.

**To find Proper Nouns, look for the `NNP` tag:**

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentence = "Michael Jackson likes to eat at McDonalds"
tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
# [('Michael', 'NNP'), ('Jackson', 'NNP'), ('likes', 'VBZ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('eat', 'VB'), ('at', 'IN'), ('McDonalds', 'NNP')]

propernouns = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NNP']
# ['Michael','Jackson', 'McDonalds']
```

You may not be very satisfied since `Michael` and `Jackson` is split into 2 tokens, then you might need something more complex such as Name Entity tagger.

By right, as documented by the `penntreebank` tagset, for possessive nouns, you can simply look for the `POS` tag, http://www.mozart-oz.org/mogul/doc/lager/brill-tagger/penn.html. But often the tagger doesn't tag `POS` when it's an `NNP`.

**To find Possessive Nouns, look for str.endswith("'s") or str.endswith("s'"):**

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentence = "Michael Jackson took Daniel Jackson's hamburger and Agnes' fries"
tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
# [('Michael', 'NNP'), ('Jackson', 'NNP'), ('took', 'VBD'), ('Daniel', 'NNP'), ("Jackson's", 'NNP'), ('hamburger', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ("Agnes'", 'NNP'), ('fries', 'NNS')]

possessives = [word for word in sentence if word.endswith("'s") or word.endswith("s'")]
# ["Jackson's", "Agnes'"]
```

Alternatively, you can use NLTK `ne_chunk` but it doesn't seem to do much other unless you are concerned about what kind of Proper Noun you get from the sentence:

```
>>> from nltk.tree import Tree; from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
>>> [chunk for chunk in ne_chunk(tagged_sent) if isinstance(chunk, Tree)]
[Tree('PERSON', [('Michael', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('Jackson', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('Daniel', 'NNP')])]
>>> [i[0] for i in list(chain(*[chunk.leaves() for chunk in ne_chunk(tagged_sent) if isinstance(chunk, Tree)]))]
['Michael', 'Jackson', 'Daniel']
```

Using `ne_chunk` is a little verbose and it doesn't get you the possessives.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I implemented it as a console script last November - https://github.com/dereckson/extract-proper-nouns - and successfully imported the list of the proper names from a novel.

Comment: Glad that the answer help, it's great to see that you have a ready solution for other people who's trying to perform the same task =)

Comment: Is it possible to use nltk for extracting proper nouns from some _unstructured_ text like a log file where proper nouns are with **mixed case** and text is **not  completely grammatically correct**? Thanks

Comment: @user2436428 Not really but there's no harm trying. It's sort of an irony to have improper proper nouns. What you need is something more like a named entity recognition, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439208/nltk-stanfordnertagger-how-to-get-proper-nouns-without-capitalization/34458164#34458164

Comment: @alvas nltk is asking me to do nltk.download() in order to use it. But it is giving error HTTP 405 Not allowed?

Comment: Are you sure the first word in the sentence is tagged as `NNP` ? To check. Depends on the version perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is a **tagger**, a part-of-speech tagger. This tool assigns a **part-of-speech tag** (e.g., proper noun, possesive pronoun etc) to each word in a sentence.

**NLTK** includes some taggers: 
http://nltk.org/book/ch05.html

There's also the [Stanford Part-Of-Speech Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) (open source too, better performance).