# Parse text to get the proper nouns (names and organizations) - python nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to extract proper nouns as in Names and Organization names from very small chunks of texts like sms, the basic parsers available with nltk [Finding Proper Nouns using NLTK WordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669952/finding-proper-nouns-using-nltk-wordnet) are being able to get the nouns but the problem is when we get proper nouns **not** starting with a capital letter , for texts like this the names like sumit do not get recognized as proper nouns

```
>>> sentence = "i spoke with sumit and rajesh and Samit about the gridlock situation last night @ around 8 pm last nite"
>>> tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
>>> print tagged_sent
[('i', 'PRP'), ('spoke', 'VBP'), ('with', 'IN'), **('sumit', 'NN')**, ('and', 'CC'), ('rajesh', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), **('Samit', 'NNP'),** ('about', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('gridlock', 'NN'), ('situation', 'NN'), ('last', 'JJ'), ('night', 'NN'), ('@', 'IN'), ('around', 'IN'), ('8', 'CD'), ('pm', 'NN'), ('last', 'JJ'), ('nite', 'NN')]
```

Comment: You could try truecasing before applying the named entity recognizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [python-nameparser](https://code.google.com/p/python-nameparser/).
It tries to guess [capitalization](https://code.google.com/p/python-nameparser/#Capitalization_Support) of names also. Sorry for the incomplete answer but I don't have much experience using python-nameparser.

Best of luck!

Comment: Well its just a nameparser like netgender, As long as you have a name you can parse it, but the idea is to extract names, no matter if they are written like "sumit" or "Sumit" or "SUMIT"

Answer (score 9):

There is a better way to extract names of people and organizations

```
from nltk import pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.tokenize import SpaceTokenizer

tokenizer = SpaceTokenizer()
toks = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
pos = pos_tag(toks)
chunked_nes = ne_chunk(pos) 

nes = [' '.join(map(lambda x: x[0], ne.leaves())) for ne in chunked_nes if isinstance(ne, nltk.tree.Tree)]
```

However all **Named Entity Recognizers** commit errors. If you really don't want to miss any proper name, you could use a dict of Proper Names and check if the name is contained in the dict.

Comment: thanks @mbatchkarov if i do have a vast dictionary of names ( which i do have) how do i make one in python, please advise, your answer looks good I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
def get_entities(self,args):
    qry = "who is Mahatma Gandhi"
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(qry)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    sentt = nltk.ne_chunk(pos, binary = False)
    print sentt
    person = []
    for subtree in sentt.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'PERSON'):
        for leave in subtree.leaves():
            person.append(leave)
    print "person=", person
```

You can get names of person, organization, locations with the help of this ne_chunk() function. Hope it helps. Thankz