# Python 2.7: How to identify unique string from string in pandas dataframe and print designated value in a specified column based on the result?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement, pandas

I have been researching similar questions but have not been able to find answers. I would appreciate if you could help me since I am new to programming and Python(2.7)..

So I have this panda dataframe.

**This is a data I have:** 
[image]

What I would like to do is that putting 1 in a man column, if a "man" string is contained in info column( and in the same row). Otherwise, I would like to put 0. The same for woman column. So, what I want is something like this.

**This is what I want to create:**
[image]

Is there any way I can create a function which identifies specified string, such as man or woman in info column, and puts 1 or 0 in man and woman columns accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New Answer

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([['Age is 83,sex is man'],
                          ['sex is woman,age is 74']],
                         columns=['info'])

mw = dataframe['info'].str.extract(r'sex is (woman|man)', expand=False)
pd.concat([dataframe, pd.get_dummies(mw).astype(int)], axis=1)
```

#### Old Answer

```
dataframe['man'] = dataframe['info'].str.match(r'^.*sex is man.*$', re.I).astype(int)
dataframe['woman'] = dataframe['info'].str.match(r'^.*sex is woman.*$', re.I).astype(int)
dataframe
```

[image]

you might also [find this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37123919/2336654) interesting.

Comment: @yusuke0426 don't forget to mark it as the answer if it does answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
import string
df['woman'] = df['info'].map(lambda x: x.translate(None, string.punctuation)).map(lambda x: 1 if 'woman' in x.lower().split() else 0)
df['man'] = df['info'].map(lambda x: x.translate(None, string.punctuation)).map(lambda x: 1 if 'man' in x.lower().split() else 0)
df
```

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrHCc.png)