# Python - Group Sequential Array Members

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I want to edit my text like this:

```
arr = [] 
# arr is full of tokenized words from my text
```

For example:

```
"Abraham Lincoln Hotel is very beautiful place and i want to go there with
 Barbara Palvin. Also there are stores like Adidas ,Nike , Reebok."
```

Edit: Basically I want to detect Proper Names and group them by using istitle() and isAlpha() in for statement like:

```
for i in arr:
    if arr[i].istitle() and arr[i].isAlpha
```

In the example arr appened until the next word hasn't his first letter upper case.

```
arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] = arr[0]
#Abraham Lincoln Hotel
```

This is what i want with my new arr:

`['Abraham Lincoln Hotel'] is very beautiful place and i want to go there with` `['Barbara Palvin']. ['Also'] there are stores like ['Adidas'], ['Nike'],` `['Reebok'].`

"Also" is not problem for me it will be usefull when i try to match with my dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Proper Nouns using NLTK WordNet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669952/finding-proper-nouns-using-nltk-wordnet)

Comment: I want a basic python code and this always returns proper names without grouping them but thanks anyway.

Comment: You cant do a *basic python code* to return proper names. It's not that easy and you need to use `NTLK` in order to archieve it.

Comment: The problem with using `istitle()` is that will also take the `Also` world as it's capitalized after the dot.

Comment: i will check the the Proper names with my datasets. Thats why i dont want to use nltk. I create my own language process program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sentence = "Abraham Lincoln Hotel is very beautiful place and i want to go there with Barbara Palvin. Also there are stores like Adidas, Nike, Reebok."
all_words = sentence.split()
last_word_index = -100
proper_nouns = []
for idx, word in enumerate(all_words):
    if(word.istitle() and word.isalpha()):
        if(last_word_index == idx-1):
            proper_nouns[-1] = proper_nouns[-1] + " " + word
        else:
            proper_nouns.append(word)
        last_word_index = idx
print(proper_nouns)
```

This code will:

- Split all the words into a list
- Iterate over all of the words and

  - If the last capitalized word was the previous word, it will append it to the last entry in the list
  - else it will store the word as a new entry in the list
  - Record the last index that a capitalized word was found

Comment: This outputs `['Abraham Lincoln Hotel', 'Barbara', 'Also']`, not `['Abraham', 
'Lincoln', 
'Hotel', 
'Barbara', 
'Palvin.', 
'Adidas', 
'Nike',
'Reebok.']`

Comment: Words like "Also" or  "Because" wont be problem for me because they wont match with my datasets which are full of organizaton , location and person names later. So any solution like ; ['Abraham Lincoln Hotel'] , ['Barbara Palvin'] ,['Adidas'], ['Nike'], ['Reebok'] will be usefull. Because later i will send them grouped words to my functions as inputs.

Comment: The code you wrote did what i want but only for first letter. Output is:['Abraham Lincoln Hotel', 'Barbara', 'Also']

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking?

```
sentence = "Abraham Lincoln Hotel is very beautiful place and i want to go there with Barbara Palvin. Also there are stores like Adidas ,Nike , Reebok."

chars = ".!?,"                                   # Characters you want to remove from the words in the array

table = chars.maketrans(chars, " " * len(chars)) # Create a table for replacing characters
sentence = sentence.translate(table)             # Replace characters with spaces

arr = sentence.split()                           # Split the string into an array whereever a space occurs

print(arr)
```

The output is:

```
['Abraham',
 'Lincoln',
 'Hotel',
 'is',
 'very',
 'beautiful',
 'place',
 'and',
 'i',
 'want',
 'to',
 'go',
 'there',
 'with',
 'Barbara',
 'Palvin',
 'Also',
 'there',
 'are',
 'stores',
 'like',
 'Adidas',
 'Nike',
 'Reebok']
```

Note about this code: any character that is in the `chars` variable will be removed from the strings in the array. Explenation is in the code.

To remove the non-names just do this:

```
import string
new_arr = []

for i in arr:
    if i[0] in string.ascii_uppercase:
        new_arr.append(i)
```

This code will include ALL words that start with a capital letter.

To fix that you will need to change `chars` to:

```
chars = ","
```

And change the above code to:

```
import string
new_arr = []
end = ".!?"    

b = 1
for i in arr:
    if i[0] in string.ascii_uppercase and arr[b-1][-1] not in end:
        new_arr.append(i)
    b += 1
```

And that will output:

```
['Abraham', 
'Lincoln', 
'Hotel', 
'Barbara', 
'Palvin.', 
'Adidas', 
'Nike',
'Reebok.']
```

Comment: This is not the correct approach. I mean, it's imposible for the OP to make a list of all the words that *are not proper names*.

Comment: Edited. @ArdaNalbant You should find more criteria that fits or does not fit the names you need to identify so the program is more precise.

Comment: The output is what i needed let me try. Good job here

Comment: i declare utf-8, will it effect the output ? edit : nope it didn't

Comment: No. It will not. (at least not on Python 3)

Comment: Is there a way to grouping them ? The output is okey but i want my current arr is changed like this: arr[0]="[Abraham Lincoln Hotel]" arr[12]="[Barbara Palvin]".Thank you.

Comment: You could group all words that start with a capital in a row, however then names like "Republic of the..." that contain words that start with lowercase  letters will be seperated.

Comment: the code you writed wont append nike and reebok. How can i manage the punctuation before the specific word ?