# Finding the position of a proper noun in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, position, enumerate

I'm wondering how to find the position of a proper noun in a list in Python. I'm aware of how to find the position of a particular word in a `list` like this:

```
for position, item in enumerate(list):
    if item == 'word':
        print position
```

ideally I would like to be able to find the position of the proper nouns in the text and then find the nearest proper noun to the `'word'`.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just need to find if the first letter if capitalized?
If that is the case, and no other rules apply, this is quite simple:

```
for position, item in enumerate(list):
    if item[0].upper() == item[0]:
        print position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nltk toolkit and its Part-Of-Speech tagger. Have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669952/finding-proper-nouns-using-nltk-wordnet) for an example.